# Link to a google sheets value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs, google-query-language

**Background**

I have a google sheet to which I regularly add rows.  Each row has an identifier column that remains constant (e.g. the row's "Title").  Rows change positions as I sort the spreadsheet on a column (e.g. the row's "Value").

For each row, I have an associated google doc with extended narrative about the content of the row.  The content doesn't belong in the sheet.

**The ask**

How do I add a link to the google doc such that when I click it, I'm taken to the corresponding row in the google sheet?

**What I've tried**

I can create a link that specifies a cell in the sheet (like "A1"), however as I add rows and re-sort the sheet, the link no longer points to the correct row.

**Thoughts**

- Can I create a google sheet link that performs a query or filter?  In this case a query that searches for a title.  I expect it to look something like,

  ```
  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ssid/edit#gid=sid?query=equals('Title', 'MyTitle')
  ```
- Does this need to be something for which I create a google apps script that's present in the google doc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Can I create a google sheet link that performs a query or filter?

Yes, but it won't take you to the Google sheets file itself. You can create a custom html link. The end point is `/gviz/tq`. Query can be added with url query parameter `tq`(say `"where A="mytitle"`) and format can be added with `tqx`(say `html`). The link should look like:

> `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/${SPREADSHEET_ID}/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=where%20A%3D%22mytitle%22`

`out:html` uses cookie authentication and should work with private files(when logged in), while `out:json` requires `oauth`  access tokens.

#### References:

- [Request format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source?hl=en#request-format)
- [Spreadsheets to gviz](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/spreadsheets?hl=en#creating-a-chart-from-a-separate-spreadsheet)

Comment: Having said that, you maybe able to get a dynamic full link with apps script, triggered to run every few hours or so, setting the new `?range=A${row that matches title}` link to Google docs.